# .NET Remoting over WCF?

Tags: wcf, .net-remoting

Why would you use [.NET Remoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting) over [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)?

I understand that WCF has its distinct advantages, but what advantages would .NET Remoting offer you over the more modern WCF technology?

Comment: There are plenty questions related to .NET Remoting vs. WCF, but the answers on this question satisfy your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452268/remoting-or-wcf-for-new-development-between-two-net-apps-on-the-same-machine-u

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WCF provides the ability to essentially do exactly what .NET Remoting does through the choice of binding you use when configuring your WCF service.

WCF abstracts the idea of a service from the transport technology that is used to implement that service. You can define a WCF service and then change the transport technology used to provide that service through configuration, one of these being net/tcp which is essentially the technology .NET Remoting uses.

WCF is more of a replacement for .NET Remoting than an alternative.

Comment: Didn't exactly answer the question though.

Comment: Of course it answers the question. I think it is a great answer that explains that WCF is a replacement for remoting than an alternative. Asking to compare WCF and remoting is asking to compare apples to oranges, as WCF does remoting.

Comment: @Darin - so it's more like comparing apple and apple pie then ... ;)

Comment: From what I understand I would say it's more like an apple to an apple dipped in caramel and covered in nuts.

Comment: This is a fine answer.  The answer is "you wouldn't, because Microsoft intends you to use WCF over .NET Remoting", which is what Simon answered.

Answer (score 3):

WCF is .NET Remoting's replacement. It can do HTTP based transport and also TCP/IP based tranport, both secure or not secure, (you can plug in to WCF any serializing engine you want) and it's easier to define and maintain.
So I don't think .NET Remoting have anything over WCF, maybe it helps you to go deep and low level, but why go the hard way?

Comment: I never used .NET Remoting, but now I want to develop Windows based smart-client application. Should I go with WCF?