# System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Requested Service not found

Tags: c#, .net, class-library, .net-remoting

I have the following code in my `Web.Config` in a remoting project which is having a reference to a dll of another class library. The class library has the following class inside it:

```
public class Generator: MarshalByRefObject, IGenerator
    {
}
```

When I run the remoting project for the configured uri which is exposing the above class, I get the mentioned error in the question header.

The url I run is this:
`http://localhost/documentgenerationserver/Generator.rem`

```
<application>
      <service>
        <wellknown mode="SingleCall" objectUri="Generator.rem" type="ABC.Generator, Generator" />
      </service>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="http" />
        <serverProviders>
          <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
        </serverProviders>
      </channels>
    </application>
```

Can someone advise me, how to resolve this issue?

`EDIT 1:` After going through an article on remoting on google, I tried appending `?wsdl` to my `URL` above and it worked. It shows me WSDL file for my remote object. In my `Client Project` which is an asp.net web application hosted in `IIS 7.5`, when I instantiate the remote object using following:

`Activator.GetObject()`

It successfully instantiates, but when I use this proxy of remote to call its method, it does not reach up to that method and returns immediately.

Can some one please help me knowing, how can I at least debug it and see, what's happening. Why it is not reaching to the remote object method?

Comment: Slightly related note - remoting was deprecated quite awhile ago in favor of WCF. It's not really suitable for new development. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294494/is-net-remoting-really-deprecated

Comment: But what about the previous project that was written 5-10 years back and someone is working on it and struggling with it. I needed some help here.

Comment: I said for *new* development.

Comment: Please show the *full* code you use to successfully connect with `Activator.GetObject()`. Also show the code you use when attempting to connect the other way. Finally, is this a Web application? If not, I would expect that configuration to be in App.config on the client side, not Web.config.

Answer (score -1):

The message "System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Requested Service not found" is the expected behavior on the browser for a remoting service.