# Trying to load dll into Application domain

Tags: c#, applicationdomain

I am trying to do the following:

```
if(domain != null)
{
    AppDomain.Unload(domain);
}

domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(appDomainName);

Assembly assembly = domain.Load(location);
```

and the code throws FileLoadException

but when i do the following there is no exception :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(location);
```

Could you please tell me what could be the problem.

Thank you.

Edited:

The reason I want to load the assembly it because i want to create instance of the class is in it using factory method of it could please suggest a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Suzanne Cook's .NET CLR Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/16/57188.aspx):

> AppDomain.Load() is only meant to be called on AppDomain.CurrentDomain. (It's meant for interop callers only. They need a non-static method, and Assembly.Load() is static.) If you call it on a different AppDomain, if the assembly successfully loads in the target appdomain, remoting will then try to load it in the calling appdomain, potentially causing a FileNotFoundException/SerializationException for you.
>
> If you need to execute an exe, use AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly() or (starting in v2.0) AppDomain.ExecuteAssemblyByName() instead. Otherwise, you should change to use Assembly.Load() from within the target appdomain. See [Executing Code in Another AppDomain](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/06/12/57169.aspx) for more info.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88717/loading-dlls-into-a-separate-appdomain).

Comment: The reason I want to load the assembly it because i want to create instance of the class is in it using factory method of it could please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directories are setup correctly on the appdomain use a AppDomainSetup if they arent..

Im not 100% sure but i don't think domain.Load takes a path, i think it wants the assembly name..

Edit:

Look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wcywcds.aspx)

look at Remarks:

**This method should be used only to load an assembly into the current application domain**. This method is provided as a convenience for interoperability callers who cannot call the static Assembly.Load method. To load assemblies into other application domains, use a method such as CreateInstanceAndUnwrap.

For information that is common to all overloads of this method, see the Load(AssemblyName) method overload.