# how to load in new appdomain from filepath?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

İ am sorry it is too classic problem loading dll. But i can not solve this basic problem: i have a plugins file path i want to load these assembly into new domain but i can not do this. Firstly; it is a web application my code below: thanks your help :

```
     foreach (var filePath in arryFiles)
                {
                    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(filePath.ToString());
                    AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
                    domainSetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                    domainSetup.DisallowBindingRedirects = false;
                    domainSetup.DisallowCodeDownload = true;
                    domainSetup.LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.SingleDomain;
                    domainSetup.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
                    ApplicationHost = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Ops.Mgr.Service", null, domainSetup);
                    // how to load into domain my assembly...

                }
```

Thanks  your helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to load assembly in to same App Domain or different App Domain?
Here is the solution to load assembly in different App Domain: [Loading DLLs into a separate AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88717/loading-dlls-into-a-separate-appdomain)

For loading assembly in same App Domain: [Can I load a .NET assembly at runtime and instantiate a type knowing only the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na)