# Dynamic loading and using a DLL in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I want to load a DLL in C# dynamically so i can unload it at execution time. I found some articles but none really helped me. I need to unload the DLL because it does not provide any functions to release/clean up the memory. The actual problem: Its a hardware driver (CAN-USB) and i need to restart my application if the hardware gets disconnected, which is very annoying. If i could load it into an assembly (or something like that) i could "unload" respectively "reload" it. I would need a short and minimalistic, but relating example how to load my dll and how to import and use the dll functions. I attached a screenshot how i am using them right now.

What I need summarized:

1. Example on how to load a dll (of the attached type) dynamically and how to use its functions.
2. How to unlead/reload the dll in case of hardware disconnection.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

[image: dll functions]

**EDIT 1:**
I have now implemented it like it is described in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx) approach but it does **not** solve my problem. The CAN-USB-Hardware blocks until i close my application and start it again. Did i do something wrong or does anyone have any other suggestions how to solve my initial problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace InDiPro
{
    public struct canData
    {
        public uint id;
        public uint length;
        public byte data0;
        public byte data1;
        public byte data2;
        public byte data3;
        public byte data4;
        public byte data5;
        public byte data6;
        public byte data7;
    }

    public class EsdCanDriver
    {
        private IntPtr pDll;
        private string dllPath;

        private IntPtr fptrCanOpen;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanOpen(int net, int mode, int txqueueSize, int rxqueueSize, int txTimeout, int rxTimeout, ref int handle);
        private static CanOpen _canOpen;
        public int canOpen(int net, int mode, int txqueueSize, int rxqueueSize, int txTimeout, int rxTimeout, ref int handle)
        {
            return _canOpen(net, mode, txqueueSize, rxqueueSize, txTimeout, rxTimeout, ref handle);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanClose;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanClose(int handle);
        private static CanClose _canClose;
        public int canClose(int handle)
        {
            return _canClose(handle);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanSetBaudrate;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanSetBaudrate(int handle, int baudrate);
        private static CanSetBaudrate _canSetBaudrate;
        public int canSetBaudrate(int handle, int baudrate)
        {
            return _canSetBaudrate(handle, baudrate);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanGetBaudrate;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanGetBaudrate(int handle, ref int baudrate);
        private static CanGetBaudrate _canGetBaudrate;
        public int canGetBaudrate(int handle, ref int baudrate)
        {
            return _canGetBaudrate(handle, ref baudrate);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanIdAdd;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanIdAdd(int handle, int id);
        private static CanIdAdd _canIdAdd;
        public int canIdAdd(int handle, int id)
        {
            return _canIdAdd(handle, id);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanIdDelete;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanIdDelete(int handle, int id);
        private static CanIdDelete _canIdDelete;
        public int canIdDelete(int handle, int id)
        {
            return _canIdDelete(handle, id);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanSend;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanSend(int handle, ref canData msg, ref int length);
        private static CanSend _canSend;
        public int canSend(int handle, ref canData msg, ref int length)
        {
            return _canSend(handle, ref msg, ref length);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanTake;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanTake(int handle, ref canData msg, ref int length);
        private static CanTake _canTake;
        public int canTake(int handle, ref canData msg, ref int length)
        {
            return _canTake(handle, ref msg, ref length);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanWrite;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanWrite(int handle, ref canData msg, ref int length, ref int dummy);
        private static CanWrite _canWrite;
        public int canWrite(int handle, ref canData msg, ref int length, ref int dummy)
        {
            return _canWrite(handle, ref msg, ref length, ref dummy);
        }

        private IntPtr fptrCanRead;
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int CanRead(int handle, ref canData msg, ref int length, ref int dummy);
        private static CanRead _canRead;
        public int canRead(int handle, ref canData msg, ref int length, ref int dummy)
        {
            return _canRead(handle, ref msg, ref length, ref dummy);
        }

        public EsdCanDriver(string dllPath)
        {
            this.dllPath = dllPath;
        }

        public bool LoadDriver()
        {
            pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(this.dllPath);
            if(pDll == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                fptrCanOpen = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canOpen@28");
                if (fptrCanOpen == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canOpen = (CanOpen)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanOpen, typeof(CanOpen));

                fptrCanClose = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canClose@4");
                if (fptrCanClose == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canClose = (CanClose)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanClose, typeof(CanClose));

                fptrCanSetBaudrate = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canSetBaudrate@8");
                if (fptrCanSetBaudrate == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canSetBaudrate = (CanSetBaudrate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanSetBaudrate, typeof(CanSetBaudrate));

                fptrCanGetBaudrate = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canGetBaudrate@8");
                if (fptrCanGetBaudrate == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canGetBaudrate = (CanGetBaudrate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanGetBaudrate, typeof(CanGetBaudrate));

                fptrCanIdAdd = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canIdAdd@8");
                if (fptrCanIdAdd == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canIdAdd = (CanIdAdd)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanIdAdd, typeof(CanIdAdd));

                fptrCanIdDelete = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canIdDelete@8");
                if (fptrCanIdDelete == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canIdDelete = (CanIdDelete)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanIdDelete, typeof(CanIdDelete));

                fptrCanSend = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canSend@12");
                if (fptrCanSend == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canSend = (CanSend)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanSend, typeof(CanSend));

                fptrCanTake = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canTake@12");
                if (fptrCanTake == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canTake = (CanTake)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanTake, typeof(CanTake));

                fptrCanWrite = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canWrite@16");
                if (fptrCanWrite == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canWrite = (CanWrite)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanWrite, typeof(CanWrite));

                fptrCanRead = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "__canRead@16");
                if (fptrCanRead == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
                _canRead = (CanRead)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fptrCanRead, typeof(CanRead));

                return true;
            }         
        }

        public bool FreeDriver()
        {
            return NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pDll);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to search for existing code? The important functions you need to call are LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress, here's an example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm not able to see the page - the link as provided doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Too late for me to edit that comment, but let's try again: [Dynamically calling an unmanaged dll from .NET (C#)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx) Some dots and similar mangled the link but this seems to work.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Great link! I didn't actually know you could do that and it looks even quite simple.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thx! Can you explain how to usw that for my functions? Where do i have to put the entry point etc.? Would be nice if you can (fully) explain for one of my functions from the screenshot!

Comment: I have implemented that approach but it does not solve my problem. Read Edit 1 please.

Answer (score 3):

You are using DLLImport, so you are importing function from a native assembly, so you need to use the same function that you will use in native languages : LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress, FreeLibrary.
These functions perform the following tasks:

> LoadLibrary : Loads the DLL into memory and returns a raw address of
> the DLL’s handle. If the DLL cannot be found, returns IntPtr.Zero.
>
> GetProcAddress :  Loads a function by name from the DLL. Returns a raw
> address of the function. If the function cannot be found, returns
> IntPtr.Zero.
>
> FreeLibrary : Releases the DLL loaded by the LoadLibrary
> function.

An example of use of LoadLibrary could be :

```
 IntPtr address = win32.GetProcAddress(m_dll, moduleName);
 System.Delegate fn_ptr = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(address, typeof(T));
```

While an example of FreeLibrary could be :

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string moduleName); 
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]  
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule); 
// Unload the DLL by calling GetModuleHandle and FreeLibrary.  
FreeLibrary(GetModuleHandle(moduleName));
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to use the above `canOpen` function (see original screenshot) with the `LoadLibrary` approach?

Comment: I would appreciate that!

Comment: I have implemented that approach but it does not solve my problem. Read Edit 1 please.

Answer (score 1):

You can not really unload a DLL in .NET. Neither an assembly nor a native DLL that's loaded when accessing a function imported vial `DllImport`.

You can, however, remove *application domains*. So the usual way of unloading a DLL is to load it in a separate application domain and then throw that away if the DLL is no longer needed.

I've actually not tried this, but you *could* try to generate an interface .NET DLL that exposes the `DllImports` as a class and then load this DLL into a separate application domain. If you free the domain, in theory, the native DLL should be unloaded, too.

---

Of course, another way could be to use `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` to load/unload the DLL, but I don't know how to access DLL functions then.

Comment: Why can't you unload a dll that is loaded dynamically with LoadLibrary? Doesn't FreeLibrary unload it when the reference count reaches 0?

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to say. Of course you can use `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary`, but not together with `DllImport`. I'll clarify. I've not yet seen DLL functions being used from DLLs loaded with `LoadLibrary`, so I can not give an example for that.

Comment: I have read about your approach but i dont understand how to use it respectively initialize my function prototypes. Thats the reason why i asked for an related example or preferably an explenation with my functions from my screenshot. But i appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Well, all you need to do is create a .NET DLL that uses `DllImport` normally as you have done in your screenshot. Create a public class that exposes a method per `DllImport`-function that calls the function. You just don't reference the DLL from your project, but load it into a new application domain as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88717/loading-dlls-into-a-separate-appdomain. You can later unload the application domain using `AppDomain.Unload(domain);`. This should also unload the native DLL.